# IOS - Memory exhausted when generating MD5 of local images

Tags: ios, swift, crash, photosframework

I'm working on an app to upload photos from users Camera Roll. As part of the upload I need to calculate MD5 of the photos (to check for duplicates before uploading). Currently the app crashes frequently due to malloc errors.

In order to track down the problem I created a simple test program which only generates MD5 of all photos on the device, and this program crashes in the same way.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPhotos: UILabel!
let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
lazy var imageRequestOptions : PHImageRequestOptions = {
    var options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.isSynchronous = false
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    return options
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil).firstObject
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

    let allImages = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection!, options: options)


    allImages.enumerateObjects({
        asset, index, stop in
        self.imageManager.requestImageData(for: asset , options: self.imageRequestOptions, resultHandler: {
            imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
            if imageData != nil {
                    let digestLength = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
                    var md5Buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)

                    let _ = imageData!.withUnsafeBytes { (body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
                        CC_MD5(body, CC_LONG(imageData!.count), &md5Buffer)
                    }

            }
        })

    })


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This program will process about 50 photos before failing with the following error:

```
2016-10-14 15:51:41.565468 PhotoLoadTest[3513:804150] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(7679134) failed'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1910101c0 0x18fa4855c 0x191010108 0x191a6265c 0x191a38ac8 0x191a03404 0x100720fa8 0x1006c31f8 0x100015a38 0x19c77e930 0x10098525c 0x10098521c 0x10098a284 0x190fbdf2c 0x190fbbb18 0x190eea048 0x19296d198 0x196ec3818 0x196ebe550 0x100017ca8 0x18fecc5b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When running the program through Instruments I see that the persistent memory use climbs to 1.6 GB before the program crashes.

If I comment out the call to `CC_MD5` the program works fine...

I don't immediately see where this program leaks memory. Do you have any ideas why this crashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
autoreleasepool{
allImages.enumerateObjects({
        asset, index, stop in
        self.imageManager.requestImageData(for: asset , options: self.imageRequestOptions, resultHandler: {
            imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
            if imageData != nil {
                    let digestLength = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
                    var md5Buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)

                    let _ = imageData!.withUnsafeBytes { (body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
                        CC_MD5(body, CC_LONG(imageData!.count), &md5Buffer)
                    }

            }
        })

    })

}
```

Above code might work as you are iterating through all of the image autorelease pool will take care of memory management.